# How to exchange two specific characters in linux？

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to exchange two characters in a complex textfile but it doesn't work.
It look like this:

```
cat 1
_**A** # 2 # 118 # -1 # ID=**B**;partial=10;start_type=GTG
GTGTCAAAAGGCAAGTTAACCTTCGCAATCAACTTCGCATTGGTAGGTGCGTATCTGGGCGCCATTAAGA

_**C** # 100 # 204 # -1 # ID=**D**;partial=01;start_type=Edge
GAGGAGATAAAGAAATTACAGGAAACCGATGAAGAAATAGGCAAAAACGAGCATATTGTTGCCTATCTTC
GTGCCGTTAGGGAAATGTGTCAAAAGGCAAGTTAA
```

I want to swap A and B, C and D  like this:

```
_**B** # 2 # 118 # -1 # ID=**A**;partial=10;start_type=GTG
GTGTCAAAAGGCAAGTTAACCTTCGCAATCAACTTCGCATTGGTAGGTGCGTATCTGGGCGCCATTAAGA

_**D** # 100 # 204 # -1 # ID=**C**;partial=01;start_type=Edge
GAGGAGATAAAGAAATTACAGGAAACCGATGAAGAAATAGGCAAAAACGAGCATATTGTTGCCTATCTTC
GTGCCGTTAGGGAAATGTGTCAAAAGGCAAGTTAA
```

I realize this is a tedious question... but  I can't see the solution :(

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, there is nothing wrong or right in efforts, we are all here to learn, thank you.

Comment: It's not tedious, it's OK. So you want to only switch the A in `**A**` and the C in `**C**` and leave all other As and Cs intact? (Oh, I see: You want to literally exchange A and B, that is also replace `**B**`by `**A**`, and equally with `**D** -> **C**`.)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I will update this question later!

Comment: `perl -ple 's/(\*\*.\*\*)/ $1=~y:ABCD:BADC:r /ge'`

Comment: Well, I want to do this,  but I can't think of a solution right now. Maybe '''sed''' and '''awk''' can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For the example above you can do something like this:

```
cat <file> | sed -e 's/\*\*B\*\*/\*\*A\*\*/' \ 
     -e 's/\*\*A\*\*/\*\*B\*\*/' \
     -e 's/\*\*D\*\*/\*\*C\*\*/' \
     -e 's/\*\*C\*\*/\*\*D\*\*/'
```

where the  contains the original code.

Note that the snippet above works only in case you `**A**` and `**B**` only once per line. For more complicated examples you need to check the manual of the **sed** command

Comment: For multiple substitutions per line I suppose the substitution command would be e.g. `s/\*\*A\*\*/\*\*B\*\*/g`? I.e., append a `g` for "global".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica no, it's more complicated, because if you have `ABA` and turn it into `BBB` you no longer know which were originally `B` that need to get turned into `A`